# IE9 doesn't accept this code

Tags: javascript, function, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I found this code and it is the perfect solution for my problem but i just found out it won't work in ie9. Does anyone know how to re-write this code to work in IE9? here is the javascript code for it.

```
function showonlyonev2(thechosenone) {
    var newboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var x = 0; x < newboxes.length; x++) {
        name = newboxes[x].getAttribute("class");
        if (name == 'newboxes-2') {
            if (newboxes[x].id == thechosenone) {
                if (newboxes[x].style.display == 'block') {
                    newboxes[x].style.display = 'none';
                }
                else {
                    newboxes[x].style.display = 'block';
                }
            } else {
                newboxes[x].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I ran it in jsFiddle and got this error:
Problem at line 4 character 9: Read only.

name = newboxes[x].getAttribute("class");

also here is the HTML part (short Version removed the head and body tags):

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px; width: 150px;">
            <a id="myHeader1" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes1');" >show this one only</a>
         </div>
         <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: block;padding: 5px; width: 150px;">Div #1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px; width: 150px;">
            <a id="myHeader2" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes2');" >show this one only</a>
         </div>
         <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes2" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: none;padding: 5px; width: 150px;">Div #2</div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background-color: #99CCFF; padding: 5px; width: 150px;">
            <a id="myHeader3" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes3');" >show this one only</a>
         </div>
         <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes3" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCCC; display: none;padding: 5px; width: 150px;">Div #3</div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

here is my jsFiddle view
http://jsfiddle.net/Nuker_Viper/JvLDx/13/

Comment: First, don't just post a block of code.  Tell us what you expect it to do and what you're actually seeing.  Second, that's javascript, not java.  I'm fixing the tag for you.

Answer (score 4):

Your edit makes the question clearer:

> I ran it in jsFiddle and got this error: Problem at line 4 character 9: Read only.
>
> `name = newboxes[x].getAttribute("class");`

You haven't declared `name` anywhere, so you're using `name` in some containing scope (probably global scope, e.g., `window.name`). Apparently IE9 considers that a read-only property, although I can't find any docs to support that.

In any case, you don't want to be mucking about with someone else's variable. Put `var name;` at the top of your function so you're using your *own* variable. :-)

---

*Original answer when we had to guess at what was going wrong:*

IE has a long-standing bug where it thinks the `class` attribute is called `className`, even in `getAttribute`. IE9 continues this bug in the misnamed "compatibility" mode. In standards mode, it gets it right.

The best thing to do is to avoid the issue entirely, since there's no need to use `getAttribute` for the `class` attribute; use the reflected property instead:

```
name = newboxes[x].className;
```

Comment: Is "reflected property" the correct terminology for this sort of thing? I thought it was an expando type.. uh.. thing.

Comment: @asawyer: It's the usual term for this. Really, just "property" is sufficient and probably better. `className`, `htmlFor`, `id`, `type`, `value`, etc., are not expandos. Expandos are arbitrary properties you add to an element, whereas elements *always* have these properties defined by the spec (their values may be empty strings, but they have them). (Some of these properties have fairly complex definitions -- `value`, for instance -- others are basically just another way to access the attribute.)